Understanding lag 1 auto-correlation of markov chains using eigenvalues of transition matrix of eigenvalues
I have a binary sequence [1, 0, 0, 0, 1 , 1, 0,....0], now to find the auto-correlation of this sequence with time lag 1. They suggested that the second largest eigenvalue of the transition matrix (considering the sequence as a realization of a Markov chain) can be considered as a measure of auto-correlation.I don't understand why.
To understand this I followed this post
So let's assume I have a markov chain whose transition matrix are
P =
$
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & 1-\alpha \\
1-\beta & \beta 
\end{bmatrix}
$, where $\alpha, \beta \in [0,1]$

The eigenvalues of this matrix are 1, $\alpha + \beta -1$.
The corresponding eigenvectors are $
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}
$,$\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha-1\\
1 - \beta
\end{bmatrix}$.

Now to calculate the stationary distribution, we use the definition $\pi^T P = \pi^T$. Thus $\pi = \begin{bmatrix}1-\beta\\
1-\alpha
\end{bmatrix}$.
So my auto-correlation using the steps followed here, I get the value as
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X_nX_{n+1}] &= \mathbb E[X_nX_{n+1}\mid X_n=0]\mathbb P(X_n=0)+ \mathbb E[X_nX_{n+1}\mid X_n=1]\mathbb P(X_n=1)\\
&= \frac{1-\beta}{2-\alpha - \beta}\mathbb E[X_{n+1}X_n\mid X_n=0] + \frac{1-\alpha}{2-\alpha - \beta} \mathbb E[X_{n+1}X_n\mid X_n=1] \\
&= \frac{1-\beta}{2-\alpha - \beta}\left(0 \cdot \alpha + 1 \cdot (1-\alpha) \right) + \frac{1-\alpha}{2-\alpha - \beta} \left(0 \cdot (1-\beta) + 1 \cdot \beta \right)  \\
&= \frac{(1-\beta)\cdot(1-\alpha) + \beta \cdot (1-\alpha)}{2-\alpha - \beta} \\
&= \frac{1}{1+\frac{1-\beta}{1-\alpha}}
\end{align}

Is $\pi$ a left eigenvector of the transition matrix? I have usually dealt with symmetric matrices and thus I am unfamiliar with the left eigenvector and right eigenvector, so please forgive me if I am wrong.
Is my working out of auto-correlation correct?
I don't see how the second largest eigenvalue can be a notion of auto-correlation.

